# Find particular strings in a word document and hyperlink to pdf's located in the ActiveDocument.Path

Tags: vba, pdf, hyperlink, ms-word, find

My example is as such. I have a word document that looks like:

ERN.001.001.0001

Apples and Oranges

ABC.001.001.0002

ERN.001.001.0004

Strawberries

ERN.001.001.0005

Also in the ActiveDocument.Path, I have the following files:

ERN.001.001.0001.pdf, ABC.001.001.0002.pdf, ERN.001.001.0004.pdf, ERN.001.001.0005.pdf

I want to create a script that looks for the pdf documents in the word document and hyperlinks them back to the directory.

My current code looks like this:

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()
Dim r1 As Range

Dim SearchString As String

        SearchString = "[A-Z]{1-3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,4}"

        Set r1 = ActiveDocument.Content

With r1.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Text = SearchString


Do While .Execute(Forward = True) = True
        r1.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r1, _
        Address:=ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & r1.Text & ".pdf", _
        SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=r1.Text

        r1.Collapse wdCollapseStart


Loop

End With
End Sub
```

When I run this script it finds the SearchString however it doesn't seem to understand what I'm trying to hyperlink. Does anyone have any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and Paste this Code in your VBA editor and run the Macro "CreateLinks".
Your Pattern seemed to be wrong also, I don't know why it worked for you though...

```
Sub CreateLinks()

Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
Dim SearchString$, Link$
Dim strPath$: strPath = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"

SearchString = "[A-Z]{3}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{4}" ' If the text characters are not fixed, then use: [A-Z]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,4}
    With Rng.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute(findText:=SearchString, Forward:=False) = True
            Link = strPath & Rng & ".pdf"

                ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Rng, _
                Address:=Link, _
                SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Rng.Text
                Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart

        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

## edit - result:

[image]